# How to easly change Multiindex header to one index with rearrange structure

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
symbols=["A","AA"]
df = yf.download(symbols, period='7d')
print(df.head())
```

I try to rearrange this multiindex pandas DataFrame to look like in picture, any idea

```
                            Adj Close                  Close             \
                                    A         AA           A         AA   
Date                                                                      
2023-02-28 00:00:00-05:00  141.970001  48.851852  141.970001  48.939999   
2023-03-01 00:00:00-05:00  137.509995  51.556973  137.509995  51.650002   
2023-03-02 00:00:00-05:00  141.669998  53.593296  141.669998  53.689999   
2023-03-03 00:00:00-05:00  143.929993  55.420002  143.929993  55.520000   
2023-03-06 00:00:00-05:00  143.229996  53.689999  143.229996  53.689999   

                                 High                    Low             \
                                    A         AA           A         AA   
Date                                                                      
2023-02-28 00:00:00-05:00  143.380005  50.040001  141.389999  47.799999   
2023-03-01 00:00:00-05:00  139.990005  52.959999  136.250000  50.529999   
2023-03-02 00:00:00-05:00  141.720001  53.709999  136.080002  50.049999   
2023-03-03 00:00:00-05:00  144.440002  55.740002  141.979996  53.700001   
2023-03-06 00:00:00-05:00  145.440002  54.900002  142.679993  53.380001   

                                 Open              Volume           
                                    A         AA        A       AA  
Date                                                                
2023-02-28 00:00:00-05:00  141.750000  48.250000  2342500  3871400  
2023-03-01 00:00:00-05:00  138.580002  51.290001  3132800  7599600  
2023-03-02 00:00:00-05:00  136.300003  50.189999  1879200  6467900  
2023-03-03 00:00:00-05:00  142.539993  54.330002  1147800  6158800  
2023-03-06 00:00:00-05:00  143.350006  54.009998  1153600  5129900
```

Want that:
Symbol in one new column "symbol" and get out from header

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'Symbol'})
```